# Is there any way I can downgrade to iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios4, jailbreak, downgrade

I know iOS 6 is out and almost everyone have iOS 6 (or atleast iOS 5+) on their devices. But one of my client has his own theories, he wants his app tested for iOS 4 also (who is using iOS 4 these days!!!)... I want to know is there any possibility I can downgrade my iPod touch/ iPhone 4/ iPad 2 / iPhone 3GS (any one of them) to iOS 4.

I search this on google and found that if I have SHSH blob saved for previous iOS versions then I can downgrade.. but I don't have that saved. So is there any possibility to downgrade??

Answer (score 1):

Without those blobs you won't be able to downgrade. You can always use the simulator though, or show your client the adoption rates of iOS 5 as of this June, that should convince him.

Comment: Do you have a link for information about iOS 5 adoption rates?

Comment: http://www.slashgear.com/apple-touts-massive-ios-5-adoption-at-wwdc-2012-11233225/ for example. It's probably even higher by now, and iOS 6 adoption rates are said to be twice as high as iOS 5 adoption rates were last year.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download XCode 3 and iOS SDK 4.  Go to [this link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and enter "XCode 3" in the search bar on the left.

Comment: What after installing xcode 3? how this will help in downgrading my device?

Comment: I think you have to use jailbreaking methods.  Follow these instructions: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/09/28/how-to-downgrade-ios-6-to-ios-5-1-1-a4-devices/

Comment: But instead of iOS 5.1.1, try downloading an iOS 4 version from here: http://www.idownloadblog.com/iphone-downloads/

Answer (score 0):

He should also keep his mind that if you support IOS 6 then the least configuration with IOS 4 is the version 4.3.Xcode 4.5 does not compile for any older versions.

And as mentioned already if you have not saved the SHSHs for any versions of IOS 4 before you can not get them right now.The only available SHSH  over Tinyumbrealla is 5.01 right now.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=SHSH), you can downgrade your iPhone 3GS to iOS 4.1, but not 4.3...